# What is alt-tab'ing or Windows key for me

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard

I have a problem and I am unsure how to solve it.

Something on my computer is triggering the Windows key each hour at exactly H:53 minutes. So at 8:53, 9:53, 10:53, etc. something press the windows key on my keyboard and when I am playing a video game, this is very annoying.

It does the exact same result as someone would press the windows key: My Windows 8.1 shows the menu with all the squares app. I initially thought it weas the software Classic Shell but after uninstalling it nothing changed.

I tried to look at my Task Manager and process list to see if something at the 53 minutes goes up in the CPU % but nothing in particular...

I am out of options and I have no idea what to do.

Any software of tricks to discover what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly try scanning for malware.

Comment: You should post the running processes. Also check: Start, Run, taskschd.msc -> if there are any scheduled scripts

Comment: Look in the Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys. Thanks so much for the comments.

The problem was a Schedule task that was scheduled to run each 53min of the day...

**If anyone fall on this question from Google, the Schedule Task was "ASUS Demo App UpLoad".** Probably some junk app from my Asus Laptop... I disabled it.

I know I installed the included Screensaver that I found on my laptop provided by Asus, that may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Oh the joy of pre-installed crapware